# SectionList re-renders everything unexpectedly

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-sectionlist

I'm new to React-Native, currently working a project that displays photos and its related information. The project uses the standard `SectionList`(RN 0.55).

The problem I have is that each time I add a photo, all the subcomponent in the list will be re-rendered. And I've noticed a significant slow down when the list grows to 50 something.

I have the following setup:

1. I have a redux store which contains `Data`(basically a wrapper around photo information), each time user does some action, the `Data` will be copied, modified, then reassigned back to redux store.
2. Then I have a class like following to render SectionList

```
class PhotoList extends PureComponent {
    render() {
       <SectionList
            sections={deriveData(this.props.data)}
            extraData={this.state}
            renderItem={this.onRenderItem} 
       >
    }

    onRenderItem(item) {
         return <View>
               // two nested level components to hold information
               </View>
    }

    driveData(data) {
       // do a lot of data transformation and calculate derived value
       return derivedData;
    }
}
// data is redux connected
```

My primary confusing point is that, when `SectionList` takes in `section` in my case, the data(as a whole) is already a new copy and is modified(since a new photo is added), so it causes `SectionList` to re-renders everything?

I want `SectionList` to only additionally render the photo I just added, any suggestions?

Comment: function probably returns  a new array every time render gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the data ("data transformation and calculate derived value") at action and update that on redux 'data'. Then change like the following.

```
class PhotoList extends PureComponent {
    render() {
       <SectionList
            sections={this.props.data} // Directly call data
            extraData={this.props.data}
            renderItem={this.onRenderItem} 
       >
    }

    onRenderItem(item) {
         return <View>
               // two nested level components to hold information
               </View>
    }

}
```

If you use redux then you have to handle data updating on redux. Then only the result will get.